# User to be able to log in without stating the user's password scheme possible?

Tags: hash, passwords, password-hashing

In my database, I have a PBKDF2 hash + salt for every user. My objective is for the user to be able to log in without stating the user's password (in case somebody is logging the network traffic somehow).

I was wondering if the following scheme is secure, or if there are any fallacies.

1. Client starts the login process by stating the username
2. Server returns the salt together with a string of non-pseudo random bytes (a challenge)
3. Client uses the salt to derive the hash. The challenge bytes are hashed together with the derived password hash and sent back to the server. (should I use some random salt during this process?)
4. Server verifies that the challenge hashed together with the hash in the database matches what the client sent.
5. Success! Server has implicitly verified the password without the client stating the password, and the input is never the same (cannot be reused by an attacker).

Is this a good idea?
Are there any security issues with giving up the salt?
In case the user doesn't exist and I don't want to give up that information, I could invent some fake salt based on some hash of the username.

Comment: Dear HelloWorld, if you search client-side password hashing on [security.se] you will find around [1456 results](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=client+password+hashing). I don't think [cryptography.se] needs an answer for this here. Please check those questions first and if not satisfied please ask there.

Comment: Like this one; [The client side hashing is for the peace of mind for the user that their literal password is never being received by the server, even if there is the assurance of hashing it in storage anyway. Another side benefit (or maybe a liability?) is that the hashing cost of an iterated PBKDF2 or similar rests with the client.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/23006/86735)

Comment: There are PAKE protocols, which might be useful, depending on the application.

Comment: @tylo Thanks! You got me on the right track. After doing some research, it seems that SPAKE2+ is the right way to go. My method seems pervious to offline dictionary attacks.